# HTML email not rendering properly

Tags: html, laravel, email

I've designed a very basic HTML layout for my Laravel app's emails, however, it doesn't display properly in the Spark email client (no formatting whatsoever) and in Apple Mail the preview pane shows the HTML instead of text.

[image: Apple Mail preview]

I've kept the HTML as simple as possible and rendered all of the CSS inline.

What am I missing to make this render properly? Are there any special tags I need to add or any additional formatting prior to the HTML?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Notification</title>
</head>
<body style="padding: 10px; background-color: #f6f6f6" bgcolor="#f6f6f6">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 100%; border-radius: 3px; background-color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #e9e9e9">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0; background-color: #7266ba; padding: 40px 0">
                    <p style="font-family:'Pacifico', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 2em; color: #ffffff; text-align: center">
                        Alert Message Goes Here
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 40px; color:#7266ba">
                    <p style="font-family:'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                        Body goes here
                    </p>
                    <p style="font-family:'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin-top: 30px">
                        &mdash; Company
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of Laravel and can you provide the code that is sending the email?

Comment: @CUGreen I don't think it has anything to do with Laravel because it doesn't display properly even when sending via email testing tools.

Comment: really? works fine for me. You will need to provide a bit more information on how you are sending this email.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

In a couple of instances I was only using `<p>` tags to display text. Once I placed those `<p>` tags inside a table everything started displaying correctly.